# AWS Redshift: columns into rows (wide to long)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, redash

I'm writing a query which result will be displayed as dashboard on redash. The query is basically a sum of several columns of table within a specific time range:

```
SELECT
   sum(col_A),
   sum(col_B),
   sum(col_C)
FROM
   table_X
WHERE
   timestamp > '2018-01-01'
   AND timestamp < '2018-02-01'
```

The result is something like this:

```
col_A    col_B    col_C    
123      456      789
```

However, to render the dasboard on redash properly, I need the result in long format:

```
column   sum
col_A    123
col_B    456
col_C    789
```

How can I cast the result from wide to long format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way is to use `union all`:

```
SELECT sum(col_A) FROM table_X WHERE timestamp > '2018-01-01' AND timestamp < '2018-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(col_B) FROM table_X WHERE timestamp > '2018-01-01' AND timestamp < '2018-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(col_C) FROM table_X WHERE timestamp > '2018-01-01' AND timestamp < '2018-02-01';
```

You may need to be careful about the ordering.  I would include a second column specifying which is being aggregated.

Three separate queries is not quite as bad as it sounds.  Redshift is a columnar database, so only the columns references should be read.